# How to Inject an Object From the Server?

Tags: angular, typescript, express, angular-universal

I am using Angular Universal to serve my Angular application from an Express server.

My goal is to inject an environment object (**from the server**) into my application. Thus I've created an `InjectionToken`

```js
export const ENVIRONMENT = new InjectionToken('ENVIRONMENT');
```

and provided it on the server side like this:

```js
app.engine(
  'html',
  ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppProdServerModule,
    providers: [{ provide: ENVIRONMENTS, useValue: environments }],
  })
);
```

Accessing the environment object like this works perfectly fine when the app is running on the server. But when the app runs on the client I get a `NullInjectionError`.

```js
constructor(@Inject(ENVIRONMENTS) private env) { }
```

So what is the best way to inject an object **from the server** to the whole application (also client)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client application can't know in run time what's the value of this provider should be.

It's quite hard to tell without seeing the whole use case, but, when running on the client, you can set this provider value within an HTTP request. Something like this:

```
export class SetEnvServcie () {
  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private injector: Injector
  ) { }

  setEnv(){
    this.httpClient.get('URL_OF_ENV_CONFIG').pipe(
      take(1),
      tap(config => Injector.create({
        providers: [
          { provide: ENVIRONMENT, useValue: config }
        ]
      }, parent: this.injector)
      )
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: sounds good. the url would just be a request to the express server?

Comment: what do you think of using `TransferState`? Maybe it's better because no additional http request needs to be made?

Comment: @FlorianLudewig Sure! I thought you are not rendering the application on the server for some reason. If you do, use `TransferState`. The URL should be the one who can return the config for env.